# Use an Array of objects defined in one javascript file in another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created few objects in a javascript file 'word.js' like

```
for(var i=0; i< words.length ;i++){ 
    var objc ={
        wd : words[i],
        x : 0,
        y :0,
        dr: "horizontal"
    };
}
```

and these are pushed into an array

```
var arry =[]
for(var i=0; i< words.length ;i++){ 
    arry.push({ wd: words[i], x:x,y: y, dr :direction[dir] });
}
```

Now i need to use this array into another file 'rect.js' like

```
document.write(word.arry[0].x);
```

I am sure this isn't the correct manner. What is the correct way to bring the array between files.I dont want one to return it and the other to use as function parameters.

Comment: Why not requesting/returning it, when you need it (in rect.js)? - If you are afraid of too much requests, cache it in your main script (rect.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create var array[] outside the function (so that it is global). Include that file(word.js) before using file in page, and you can use it.
e.g.

**Word.js**

```
var arry =[]

for(var i=0; i< words.length ;i++){ 
    var objc ={
        wd : words[i],
        x : 0,
        y :0,
        dr: "horizontal"
    };
}
for(var i=0; i< words.length ;i++){ 
    arry.push({ wd: words[i], x:x,y: y, dr :direction[dir] });
}
```

**rect.js file**

```
document.write(word.arry[0].x);
```

**Somefile.php or html**

```
<script src = "word.js" />
<script src = "rect.js" />
```

Comment: ya.. both the files are in src of the main idex.html file from where functions of both files are called.

Comment: Then it should work, please elaborate what error you are getting. And just in case : this is one of the correct method to do it.

Comment: its no error. Just the document.write method isn't working. Both the files have one function each which are called from the html page on window.onload. I think there is some scope problem.

Comment: Welcome, just if you can tell what the error was, so that it will help other users. You can update your question itself to tell what the error was.

Comment: oh! the scope as I said. The arry[] was declared inside the function in word.js not globally! silly mistakes.thanx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare to include the `word.js` file in the `rect.js` ?

Comment: Declare as in? they are separate files.

Comment: Javascript doesn't really work like that; you don't include. If you've got a framework like requireJS, you can do that, or if you've got a DOM, you can add a script tag, but there's no language notion of "include."